# Avoid nesting for comprehensions with monadic operations

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

I'm trying to achieve something like the following, where `a` and `b` are both intended to be of type `Option[List[Int]]`:

```
val a = List(1, 2, 3).some
val b = for {
  xs <- a
  el <- xs
} yield el + 1
```

Of course, this doesn't work because it's translated into

```
val b = a flatMap (xs => xs map (el => el + 1))
```

whereas I'm looking for

```
val b = a map (xs => xs map (el => el + 1))
```

In order to put this into a for comprehension, I have to nest them:

```
val b = for {
  xs <- a
} yield for {
  el <- xs
} yield el + 1
```

This last form works. Is there a way to get the same result using the first form? I feel like I've seen something along these lines using Kleisli composition or monad transformers but couldn't seem to find what I needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ListT` monad transformer in [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) is actually a little better than your first version (or at least more concise—you only have to worry about one layer):

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

val a = ListT(List(1, 2, 3).some)

val b = for { el <- a } yield el + 1
```

Or equivalently:

```
val b = a.map(_ + 1)
```

Here `a` and `b` are both instances of `ListT[Option, Int]`. You can unwrap these values and get a plain old `Option[List[Int]]` using `underlying`:

```
scala> b.underlying
res0: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(2, 3, 4))
```

You can do lots of other things with `ListT`, like sequence functions from values into options of lists, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I had been trying to use `a.liftM[ListT]`, but I've just realized it was lifting the inner list to a `List[List[Int]]` and wrapping its containing `Option` in a `ListT`.